# How do I use values from a tuple which is in a list of tuples as arguments for a function?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, pygame, tuples

I'm trying to construct a simple tilemap thingy, as part of a larger project, and one of the solutions I came out with was to use a function like so:

```
def tile((value, X, Y)):
    if value == 1:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0) (X, Y, 64, 64), 0)
```

The idea being that I set the level out as a list of tuples that contain a value which denotes the tile to be drawn there, and then the coordinates of that tile.

This, of course, doesn't work since you can't use a tuple as an argument.

My solution to this was to instead get the values out of the tuple in the list:

```
def tile(value, X, Y):
    if value == 1:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0) (X, Y, 64, 64), 0)


level = [(1, 0, 0), (rest of list)]
tile(level[0[0]], level[0[1]], level[0[2]])
```

Which didn't work, and gave me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
tile(level[0[0]], level[0[1]], level[0[2]])
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Does anyone have a workaround for this? Some way I can feed a tuple into a function as a series of arguments? Or am I just using a completely idiosyncratic method that won't ever work ever? I'm guessing this is just due to my blinding incompetence, although I would like to be told otherwise.

Python 2.7, pygame 1.9

Comment: You were nearly there, actually; apart from the easier `*level[0]` syntax, you *should* have used `level[0][0], level[0][1], level[0][2]`. Your code instead tried to index the integers (`0[0]` tries to get item `0` from the `int` value `0`, hence your exception).

Comment: "*This, of course, doesn't work since you can't use a tuple as an argument.*" That's news to me. Since when?

Comment: When I tried to use it as an argument, I just got TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an answer about the best way to handle your task, but the specific problem with the way you're doing it is that you need to do `level[0][0]` etc., not `level[0[0]]`.

Answer (score 1):

The error that you are experiencing can be solved by changing this:

```
tile(level[0[0]], level[0[1]], level[0[2]])
```

To this:

```
tile(level[0][0], level[0][1], level[0][2])
```

You just had the brackets in the wrong place.

Another note: you *can* use a tuple as an argument to your function, which would look like this:

```
def tile((value, X, Y)):
    if value == 1:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (X, Y, 64, 64), 0)
```

like you had in your original example. The rest of the code would then be simplified to this:

```
level = [(1, 0, 0), (rest of list)]
tile(level[0])
```

Comment: Note that the tuple-as-argument syntax was removed in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unpack your tuple when you call like this:

```
tile(*level[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You certainly may pass a tuple into a function, and your fist attempt should have worked just fine:

```
def tile((value, X, Y)):
  if value == 1:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (X, Y, 64, 64), 0) # Note typo: missing comma
level = [(1, 0, 0), (1, 10, 10), (1, 42, 99)]
for x in level:
    tile(x)
```

If you'd rather pass *all* the tiles simultaneously, you can do that, too. Just move the `for` loop into your function:

```
def tile(l):
  for value, X, Y in l:
    if value == 1:
      pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (X, Y, 64, 64), 0)
level = [(1, 0, 0), (1, 10, 10), (1, 42, 99)]
tile(level)
```

Finally, if you don't want to accept a tuple in your function, but do want to keep the data in a tuple, that is also an option. Use the `*` operator:

```
def tile(value, X, Y):
    if value == 1:
      pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (X, Y, 64, 64), 0)
level = [(1, 0, 0), (1, 10, 10), (1, 42, 99)]
for x in level:
    tile(*x)
```